# Trouble searching for specific values using XMLNAMESPACES

Tags: sql-server, sqlxml

I've taken a look and wasn't able to find an answer that would help me with my issue. (Most probably due to my poor skills)

However was hoping that someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

The issue:
I have an XML column in the table that I am querying and I need the query to return rows all rows with a specific value.

An example from the xml column

```
 <EventD xmlns="http://example1" xmlns:e3q1="http://example2" xmlns:xsi="http://example3" xsi:type="e3q1:Valuechange">
  <e3q1:NewValue>Running</e3q1:NewValue>
  <e3q1:OldValue>Stopped</e3q1:OldValue>
</EventD>
```

What I would need to do is to return all rows that have "NewValue" as "Running"

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('example2' as e3q1)
select top 100 
Xml.value('(EventD/NewValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),

* from Table1
and Xml.value('(EventD/NewValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)') like 'Running'
```

Yet this does not seem to return any rows at all, would be really grateful if someone could point out what am i doing wrong here.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This is SQL Server not MySQL. Two very different products

Comment: 1) The namespace name is `http://example2`, not `example2`; 2) you don't *specify* any namespace in your queries. Use `e3q1:NewValue`, and declare another namespace for `http://example1` so you can qualify `EventD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do declare the namespace `e3q1` (although it's missing the `http://` and you don't use it later...), but you did not declare the *default namespace*

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Xml] XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(
 N'<EventD xmlns="http://example1" xmlns:e3q1="http://example2" xmlns:xsi="http://example3" xsi:type="e3q1:Valuechange">
  <e3q1:NewValue>Running</e3q1:NewValue>
  <e3q1:OldValue>Stopped</e3q1:OldValue>
</EventD>'
);

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://example1', 'http://example2' as e3q1)
SELECT [Xml].value('(EventD/e3q1:NewValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
from @tbl AS Table1
WHERE Xml.value('(EventD/e3q1:NewValue)[1]', 'varchar(100)') like 'Running';
```

But this approach is - at least I think so - not what you really want. I think you are looking for `.nodes()`. The next lines show as alternative an approach to replace namespaces with a wildcard. But I would recommend to be as specific as possible.

```
SELECT Only.Running.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')
from @tbl AS Table1
CROSS APPLY Xml.nodes('*:EventD/*:NewValue[text()="Running"]') AS Only(Running)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like  Jeroen Mostert already says all necessary
I can only add - name of namespace is not important, only uri

```
declare @xml xml='<EventD xmlns="http://example1" xmlns:e3q1="http://example2" xmlns:xsi="http://example3" xsi:type="e3q1:Valuechange">
  <e3q1:NewValue>Running</e3q1:NewValue>
  <e3q1:OldValue>Stopped</e3q1:OldValue>
  <xsi:test>test</xsi:test>
  <test1>test1</test1>
</EventD>'


;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://example2' as test)  
select
 @xml.query('(*/test:*)')
```

compare with result of

```
select
     @xml.query('(*/*)')
```

Comment: The point is the ommited *default* namespace. You use `*`, which passes by this issue, but you should not use this approach...